# How to upload multiple parameters values in parameter store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-parameter-store

I am trying to upload multiple parameters to the aws parameter store.
What you could read there is an example to take files from a json but it only accepts one parameter.
In the same way many documentations show it as:

```
aws ssm put-parameter \
    --name "MyStringParameter1" \
    --type "String" \
    --value "Vici" \
    --overwrite

aws ssm put-parameter \
    --name "MyStringParameter2" \
    --type "String" \
    --value "Vici" \
    --overwrite
...
```

Command that only accepts one parameter:

```
aws ssm put-parameter --region us-west-2 --cli-input-json file://params.json
```

Is there a way to load several parameters in a single instant, through lambda it could be or through scripts

Comment: Yes, you have to write program that will iteratively create those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is a python script that I used to store multiple values. Update the `path/values` as well the `AWS_ACCOUNT` which is the profile name.

```
import subprocess

# Update the paramters here
parameters = {
    "path": "value",
    "path2": "value2",
    "path3": "value3",
}

# Name of the profile where you need to update the params
AWS_ACCOUNT = "aws-profile-name"
AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"
AWS_PARAMETER_TYPE = "SecureString"

for path, value in parameters.items():
    try:
        # Construct the command with PATH and VALUE as arguments
        command = [
            "aws", "ssm", "put-parameter",
            "--region", AWS_REGION,
            "--profile", AWS_ACCOUNT,
            "--name", path,
            "--value", value,
            "--type", AWS_PARAMETER_TYPE
        ]
        # Execute the command
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
        print(f"Parameter {path} successfully set.")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error setting parameter {path}: {e}")
```

Note: While running this script, after each value is stored, you will see an output such as below which you just need to close and it will continue saving the parameters

```
{
    "Version": 1,
    "Tier": "Standard"
}
```

To run  `python <name_of_this_script>.py`